# org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Namespace org.renjin:tools has no symbol named '.get_internal_S3_generics'

Tags: java, r, tm, renjin

I need to extract keywords from News data saved as a text file using my java web application. I am using Language R and Renjin for doing this text mining (package tm from Renjin Web site) and extract keywords. The script really works in RStudio but cant run using Renjin in my Java Web app. Whenever I am trying to create a Corpus this Exception happens. Please suggest me a solution.

**org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Namespace org.renjin:tools has no symbol named '.get_internal_S3_generics'**

My R script file which reads a txt file and write keywords with their frequencies into a csv file is shown below:

```
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
setwd('/home/lalkrishna/Desktop/keywordtest/')
newsfile <- scan(file = "0e3cdf1b-8fa4-4df0-8977-906d5865008b.txt",what = character() )
news_Corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(newsfile))
news_Corpus <- tm_map(news_Corpus, removePunctuation) 
news_Corpus <- tm_map(news_Corpus, removeNumbers)
news_Corpus <- tm_map(news_Corpus, tolower)

new_stopwords = scan("/home/lalkrishna/Desktop/keywordtest/stop-wordlist.csv", what = character())
updated_stopword_list = c(stopwords("english"),new_stopwords)

news_Corpus <- tm_map(news_Corpus, removeWords, updated_stopword_list)
news_Corpus <- tm_map(news_Corpus, stemDocument)
news_Corpus <- tm_map(news_Corpus, stripWhitespace)
news_Corpus <- tm_map(news_Corpus, PlainTextDocument)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(news_Corpus)
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(news_Corpus)

freqs <- as.data.frame(inspect(dtm))
colSums(freqs)  
which(apply(tdm, 1, sum) > 2)
write.csv(colSums(freqs), file = "term-freq.csv")
```

Comment: When using CRAN packages in Renjin, always check to see if they are supported. The SnowballC package is clearly not: on http://packages.renjin.org/package/org.renjin.cran/SnowballC it says "This package can be loaded by Renjin but there was an error compiling C/FORTRAN sources and all tests failed."

Comment: That make sense. Thank you @mjkallen